# javascript not loading on all pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My javascript file etheme.js is not loading on all my pages. I'm running on the newest version of wordpress and theme. The theme-functions file code is provided bellow. I've reuploaded my backup and still get this issue.

```
            if(!function_exists('etheme_enqueue_styles')) {
            function etheme_enqueue_styles() {
            global $etheme_responsive;

            $custom_css = etheme_get_option('custom_css');

            if ( !is_admin() ) {wp_enqueue_style("fa",get_template_directory_uri().'/css/font-awesome.min.css');
            wp_enqueue_style("bootstrap",get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css');
            wp_enqueue_style("parent-style",get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');
            if($etheme_responsive)
            wp_enqueue_style("responsive",get_template_directory_uri().'/css/responsive.css');  
            wp_enqueue_style("font-open-sans",et_http()."fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,300italic");
            wp_enqueue_style("font-roboto",et_http()."fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext");
            wp_enqueue_style('js_composer_front');

            if($custom_css) {
            wp_enqueue_style("custom",get_template_directory_uri().'/custom.css');}

            $etheme_color_version = etheme_get_option('main_color_scheme');

            if($etheme_color_version=='dark') {
            wp_enqueue_style("dark",get_template_directory_uri().'/css/dark.css');}

            $script_depends = array();
            if(class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
            $script_depends = array('wc-add-to-cart-variation');}

            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
            wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/modernizr.js');
            wp_enqueue_script('head', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/head.js');
            if(class_exists('WooCommerce') && is_product())
            wp_enqueue_script('zoom', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/zoom.js',array(),false,true);
            wp_enqueue_script('etheme', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/etheme.js',$script_depends,false,true);
            wp_localize_script( 'etheme', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'noresults' => __('No results were found!', ETHEME_DOMAIN)));}}}

            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'etheme_enqueue_styles', 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your HTML contents:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also try `alert('I');` to see if Javascript works.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried manually adding the script but it didn't work. This raised another red flag which caused me to look into the sites caching system. It turns out the site was not updating. I had to uninstall my caching plugin and reinstall it. Updated my theme-function file and it worked. Thank you.